# Finding a relation between several variables

Tags: constraints, multivalued-functions, relation-algebra

I'm a bit at a loss here. I know that this seems a bit like a "here's my problem, now go solve it" thing, and I'm sorry about that, but I just want a nudge in the right direction since I've never dealt with this type of problem (in more than two variables). See, I have 5 variables $A, P, H, T,$ and $M$ and I would like to find a type of relation between them they satisfy with certain constraints. Of course all this is pretty vague so let me go into the specifics.

I have:

$0 \leq A \leq 100, A \in \mathbb{R}$
$0 \leq H \leq 10, H \in \mathbb{N}$
$0 \leq T \leq 20, T \in \mathbb{N}$
$0 \leq P \leq 30, P \in \mathbb{N}$
$-14 \leq M \leq 14, M \in \mathbb{R}$

And I need a relation of the form $A = f(H,P,M,T)$. In addition, I have the following conditions the relation must satisfy:

1. If $H, P$, or $|M|$ increases, then A increases.
2. If T increases, then A decreases.
3. $P = 0 \implies A = 0$ regardless of the other variables. This can be written as $f(H, 0, M, T) = 0$.
4. The function satisfies $f(10, 30, \pm 14, 0) = 100$, so when H, P and |M| are maximized and T is minimized, the function achieves its maximum.

Till now I've thought of something like: $A = |M|\frac{PH}{T}$, but this fails to meet the conditions since T is not allowed to be 0 here and A is not always in the range $[0,100]$. From here, I can add constants to tweak the exact values I'd like the function to take on, but I need a general form of a relation I can work with.

Comment: Hint:  Well we can almost take  $$A = cP(H + P + |M|-T) $$  for any positive constant c. Only problem is that the term in the parentheses can go negative in the region (which is problematic for condition 1 in P)  but the smallest it can be is -20 so take $$A = cP(H + P + |M|-T+21) $$  This satisfies the first three constraints, and the fourth lets you solve for c.

Comment: @lulu Well, that was easy :p. This seems to work well. If you'd like to write your comment as an answer so I can accept it, that'd be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here is my comment in answer form:

Well we can almost take
$$A=cP(H+P+|M|−T)$$
for any positive constant c. Only problem is that the term in the parentheses can go negative in the region (which is problematic for condition 1 in P) but the smallest it can be is -20 so take
$$A=cP(H+P+|M|−T+21)$$
This satisfies the first three constraints, and the fourth lets you solve for c